# Query Builder for DATE type

Tags: c#, date, query-builder

I'm having a problem with my query builder. I have a datagridview which I want to filter through. I want to allow search by "NAME, SURNAME, DATE". Here is my SQL QUERY

```sql
SELECT exDate, exName, exSurname FROM examines
WHERE (exDate = @Param1) AND (exName = @Param2) AND (exSurname = @Param3)
```

And this is my C# code where I 'call' the query

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.examinesTableAdapter.FillBy(this.dbSpinDataSet.examines, dateTimePicker1.Value, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

in VS I get 2 ERRORS saying:

**"...Project1.dbSpinDataSetTableAdapters.examinesTableAdapter, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments."
"...cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' to 'string'."**

I understand where is the error but I don't know how to solve it. My query was written in 'query builder' in projects DataSet. I went to **FILTER** columns for exDate, exName and exSurname and i wrote **?** (question mark). The query builder automatically transferred it into above mentioned form *"= @Param1", "= @Param2" and "= @Param3".*

I know I can't treat the DateTime as string but don't know what to write into FILTER column of my query builder for my code to work.

Comment: What column type is the `exDate` column in your database?

Comment: Ensure that the exDate definition in your QueryBuilder is define also as a Date (or DateTime) type. That should then change your TableAdapter's FillBy to (tableadapter, datetime, string, string)

Comment: you can't define a variable in Query Builder because the tables are imported with wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a string variable, and it will work!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string your_string = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
      try
      {
          this.examinesTableAdapter.FillBy(this.dbSpinDataSet.examines, your_string, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
      }
      catch (SystemException ex)
      {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
    }
```